# Mandrill - Send HTML tags inside X-MC-MergeVars

Tags: mandrill

I tried to send HTML tags inside `X-MC-MergeVars` for my Mandrill handlebar template, but doesn't seem to work.

PHP part:

```
[...]
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("X-MC-MergeVars", json_encode(["foo" => "b<strong>a</strong>r"]));
```

Mandrill template part:

```
[...]
Here is my var {{foo}}
```

And the result

```
Here is my var b<strong>a</strong>r
```

Do you know if it's possible to Mandrill to translate HTML inside a string?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy actually.
You have to replace your double brace `{{`by triple brace `{{{`

```
[...]
Here is my var {{{foo}}}
```

[Mandrill API](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content#additions-to-standard-handlebars) (HTML escaping)

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by an {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", "{{{.